# Whether the in-memory database uses users's main memory?

Tags: database, ignite, in-memory-database

After uploading my website online, which main memory it is used to store the data?

Whether it is user's main memory or my hosting server's main memory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In-memory database uses RAM of the machine on which it runs.